# element vainished without clicking it when using toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

toggle means when you click an element, it would do something. In my case, I didn't click "news title", but it quickly vanished. Why?

Here's my code:

```js
$('h5').toggle(function() {
  $(this).next().hide();
}, function() {
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h5>news title</h5>
  <p>hdsiauhfua;hfsh;aoff</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use `.click()` for this

Comment: because you are using `.toggle()` use `.click()` instead

Comment: `toggle` does not mean that at all, it is a jQuery method to hide/show an element.

Comment: @guradio But doesn't toggle() include click function? Why does it need to add .click() ?

Comment: @skobaljic Suppose the toggle() is to hide/show an element, I chose to hide/show its next element. Why was itself hiden/shown?

Comment: Cause you ordered it, by doing `$('h5').toggle()` <- this code toggles the state of `h5`. Look at below answers, you need to toggle the element after clicking it. Please read the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) first.

Answer (score 1):

Try using code below. You can use `siblings()` to call the next element and to hide and show this next element, `toggle()` comes in.

```js
$('div p').hide();
$('h5').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h5>NEWS TITLE</h5>
  <p>Content here...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `.click()`
2. And use `.toggle()` to hide and show

```js
$('h5').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h5>news title</h5>
  <p>hdsiauhfua;hfsh;aoff</p>
</div>
```